# MySQL - Update where fields are the same

Tags: mysql

The title probably doesn't say much useful, so I'll explain. Basically I have a first query:

```
UPDATE sales_records
INNER JOIN (SELECT buyer_full_name, buyer_address_1
FROM sales_records
GROUP BY buyer_full_name, buyer_address_1
HAVING COUNT(*)>1) multiorder
ON sales_records.buyer_full_name = multiorder.buyer_full_name
AND sales_records.buyer_address_1 = multiorder.buyer_address_1
SET processed=1
WHERE sales_records.buyer_full_name<>''
AND sales_records.buyer_address_1<>''
```

So the above sets everyone who has made more than one order as processed=1. However, in the same table there are parts of the order which do not have a buyer_address_1 or a buyer_full_name but do have the same sales_record_number field. I need to update the remaining ones with the same sales_record_number to processed=1 too.

This is what I've tried (amongst other similar variations) but it doesn't work:

```
UPDATE sales_records
WHERE sales_record_number=(SELECT sales_record_number
FROM ebay_sales_records
WHERE processed=1)
AND processed=1
```

Any ideas?

Comment: try using IN clause in WHERE condition

Comment: If more than one records retrieved when `WHERE processed=1` matches, then your query doesn,t work. use `In`